# Delphi Android Services Global Variables

Tags: android, delphi, service

I'm creating an android app in Delphi with the use of geolocation where I've moved everything to the service that I also send to the foreground to make it work even with the app closed and screen phone locked.

I need access from the main app to some global variables of the service.

The problem is that these, even if they are updated by the service and work correctly for their purposes, when the main app reads them, instead, they are all zero, as if nothing had been written to them.

do you know why?

Comment: Yes. The Service is running like a DLL in Windows. You can however obtain a reference to the service in the OnServiceConnected event handler. Cast the ALocalService to your Service Module's name. All public vars in your service object are then available to the host app.